# SQL Server tables connection

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database, sql-server-2014, relationship

I have to connect multiple tables that are part of single or multiple databases.  Approximately 10-15 tables in each query have to be connected to generate data for the analysis in SQL Server 2014.

I don't have access to the database diagram or architecture and these reports are to be sent out weekly. I want to understand the approach on how to begin writing these kind of queries which are of basic and advanced level and identify the relationship between tables and what kind of advanced level queries I can learn or utilize like CTE, Rank Partition, Subqueries etc.

Anybody who can provide a rough flow diagram or structure about the approach will be really helpful.

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that owners of those source systems want to be directly queried every time someone runs a report. Since you already have access to SQL Server, I would suggest building a data warehouse with that.

You haven't provided a whole lot of information to go on, but SSIS packages could be created to connect to the source systems and load into your data warehouse. And furthermore, those packages can be scheduled through Agent.

As for modeling... Again it is difficult with the lack of information, but generally the star model works great for reporting, which is a fact table surrounded by dimension (or attribute) tables.

As for figuring out relationships without a diagram, this will have to be done via experimentation and tieing to existing reports to make sure your joins aren't dropping records or cascading.

Good luck.